# Server closes after pika.exceptions.StreamLostError: Stream connection lost

Tags: rabbitmq

I have some images in my queue and I pass each image to my flask server where processing on images is done and a response is received in my rabbitmq server. After receiving response, I get this error "pika.exceptions.StreamLostError: Stream connection lost(104,'Connection reset by peer')". This happens when rabbitmq channel again starts consuming the connection. I don't understand why this happens. Also I would like to restart the server again automatically if this error persists. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Please paste your code here that is generating the exception.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your consume process is probably taking too much time to complete and send Ack/Nack to the server. Therefore, server does not receive heartbeat from your client, and thereby stops from serving. Then, on the client side you receive:

```
pika.exceptions.StreamLostError: Stream connection lost(104,'Connection reset by peer')
```

You should see server logs as well. It is probably like this:

```
missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s
```

See [this issue](https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/1224) for mor information.

Comment: hi, do you know why I get this error even if my consume process is not taking too much time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76172079/pika-exceptions-streamlosterror-stream-connection-lost-connectionreseterror10

Answer (score 2):

Do your work on another thread. See this code as an example -

https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/master/examples/basic_consumer_threaded.py

Answer (score 2):

You can change stream connection limit if you set heartbeat in ConnectionParameters

```
connection_params = pika.ConnectionParameters(heartbeat=10)
```

wher number in seconds. It say yout TCP connection keepalive to 10 seconds for example.

More information https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html and https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html#tcp-keepalives