# pika.exceptions.StreamLostError: Stream connection lost: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

I use `pika` `basic_get` method to get message from `rabbitmq` and `basic_ack` method to do ack.

```
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host="rabbitmq", 
        heartbeat=0
    )
)
channel = connection.channel()

def mq_record():
    method_frame, _, body = channel.basic_get("test")
    if not body:
        return False, None
    if method_frame:
        channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method_frame.delivery_tag, multiple=True)
    rev_mq = eval(body.decode())
    task_id = rev_mq.get("task_id")
    level = rev_mq.get("level")
    return task_id, level

task_id, level = mq_record()
```

And here comes the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 2159, in basic_get
    self._basic_getempty_result.is_ready)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1335, in _flush_output
    self._connection._flush_output(lambda: self.is_closed, *waiters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 523, in _flush_output
    raise self._closed_result.value.error
pika.exceptions.StreamLostError: Stream connection lost: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')
```

I have learned from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57448824/10844937),

> Your consume process is probably taking too much time to complete and
> send Ack/Nack to the server. Therefore, server does not receive
> heartbeat from your client, and thereby stops from serving. Then, on
> the client side you receive the error.

However, in my case, we don't take too much time to ack. Why there is such an error? Anyone knows, thanks in advance.

Comment: What does RabbitMQ log at the same time?

Comment: @LukeBakken missed heartbeats from client

Comment: Well, there you go. Your application is blocking Pika's I/O loop and thus the ability to send/receive heartbeats. If you'd like me to investigate further you must provide code in a git repository that I can clone and run to see the issue.

Comment: @LukeBakken thanks. we have solved by close connection.